# addClass not working on dynamic list item on search functionality in laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, laravel-5

I have a search form where the user can search for the products.

**search form**

```
<form class="navbar-form pull-right no_padding m_top_0 m_bottom_0 formSearchProduct" role="search" onsubmit="return false;" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <div class="input-group p_xs_right_15 p_xs_left_15 p_sm_left_15 p_sm_right_15">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control m_xs_bottom_10 searchProduct" placeholder="Search Product" style="height: 24px; margin-top: 3px;">
        <div class="showProds">
            <ul class="searchedProducts" tabindex="0"></ul>
        </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Controller for search:

```
public function searchProduct(Request $request)
{
    $productName = $request->input('name');
    $products = Product::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $productName . '%')->get();

    return view('partials.search', compact('products'));
}
```

**search.blade.php**

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <li>
        <a href="{{ url('/store/'.$product->code .'/'.Safeurl::make($product->name)) }}" class="link_scheme_color_main">
            {{ $product->name }}
        </a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

**ajax**

```
$('.searchProduct').keydown(function(e) {
    var name = $(this).val();
    var inputData = $('.formSearchProduct').serialize();
    var prodList = $('.showProds');
    var countList = prodList.find('ul li').length;
    var prd = prodList.find('ul li');

    if (name.length === 0) {
        prodList.hide();
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ url(' / store / product / search ') }}',
            type: "POST",
            data: inputData
        }).done(function(m) {
            //setTimeout(function() {
            if (m) {
                prodList.show();
                prodList.find('ul.searchedProducts').html(m);
                prodList.find('ul li').first().addClass('activeProduct');
            } else {
                prodList.hide();
            }
            //}, 500);
        });
    }
});
```

**css**

```
.activeProduct {background: #ccc !important;}
```

The issue is that when the user presses the down / up arrow key, the class `activeProduct` does not function properly. It stays at the first list item only. I have followed [this tutorial](http://jsfiddle.net/4hd7w/8/) but failed.

After following the tutorial, I have this code that I tried to my best:

```
$('.searchedProducts').keydown(function(e) {
    var prodList = $('.showProds');
    var countList = prodList.find('ul li').length;
    var prd = prodList.find('ul li');
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if (e.which === 40) {
        var next = prd.removeClass('activeProduct').next('li');
        next = next.length > 0 ? next : $('li:eq(0)');
        next.addClass('activeProduct');
    }
});
```

The above function does not get fired at all, I don't know the reason why.

**What I want:**

After searching the products, in the dropdown, the user should be able to use up/down arrow keys, and when pressing the enter button, it should take him/her to the product page.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think it is in ` var next = prd.removeClass('activeProduct').next('li');` this part. Do you have a live example where I can test if that's correct?

Comment: Nope, I don't have any live example, I am developing it on my local machine.

Comment: Dear @Saiyan Prince are you find the solution,same problem overhere.Kindly guide me if you fixed it.Thank you

Comment: @Raham I have posted solution to this question which I'll be accepting after an hour.. You can go and give it a try..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this.

I have used a jquery plugin called [selectize.js](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/).

And [here is the tutorial](http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/laravel-shop-tutorial-3-implementing-smart-search/) that I followed to implement this in my Laravel application.

Here's the [demo link](http://demos.maxoffsky.com/shop-search/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.searchedProducts').keydown(function(e) {
    var prodList = $('.showProds');
    var countList = prodList.find('ul li').length;
    var prd = prodList.find('ul li');
    // Note this line below
    var active = prodList.find('ul li.activeProduct');

    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if (e.which === 40) {
        // And this line
        var next = active.removeClass('activeProduct').next('li');
        next = next.length > 0 ? next : $('li:eq(0)');
        next.addClass('activeProduct');
    }
});
```

The problem is that you selected all the list items and removed the class activeProduct. The next function tries to select the next list item, but you have all of them in your selection, so that is where your code doesn't work (If i'm correct). By selecting the active product, I think your code will work.

Comment: It got somewhat, but as I said, the function is not getting triggered / fired at all. If I change `$('.searchedProducts')` to `$('body')`, it does function, but it goes back to the first list element and adding the `activeProduct` class

Comment: Try `$('.searchProduct')` instead. What that does is listening to the event in the input field and making it kind of the experience you get when searching something at Google and then selecting a result from the dropdown.

Comment: Nope, it jumps back to the first list item after going to the second list item, by adding, `$('.searchProduct')`